# Trying to add a region to Drupal 7 Skeleton theme

Tags: drupal-7, region

I'm working with the Skeleton theme in Drupal 7. I've added the following to the skeletontheme.info file;

```
regions [marquee] = Marquee
```

and this in the page.tpl.php file where I want the region to be;

```
<?php if ($page['marquee']): ?>
    <div class="marquee">
        <?php print render($page['marquee']); ?>
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I cleared the cache, and reloaded the page, but I still get the following message;

Notice: Undefined index: marquee in include() (line 107 of C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\themes\skeletontheme\templates\page.tpl.php).

Do I need to add any more code to any other files to get this region to appear?

Answer (score 0):

just remove blank space before bracket in `skeletontheme.info` file,

```
regions[marquee] = Marquee
```